lsp + company giving c++ completion in c-mode
I'm facing an issue in my emacs configuration. It is that every completion that LSP gives me is for C++ and not for C. It is very inconvenient as long as it automatically puts C++ library headers at the top of my files.
Here is my LSP configuration:
(use-package lsp-mode
    :init
    ;;set prefix
    (setq lsp-keymap-prefix "C-c l")
    (setq lsp-diagnostics-provider :flycheck) ; Use flycheck for diagnostics
    (setq lsp-enable-snippet t)       ; Enable snippet support
    (setq company-idle-delay 0.2) ; Set delay for completion pop-up
    (setq company-minimum-prefix-length 1)
    (setq lsp-clients-clangd-executable "clangd")

    :hook
    ((c-mode . lsp)
     (latex-mode . lsp)
     (lsp-mode . lsp-enable-which-key-integration))
    :commands lsp
    :bind
    ("C-<return>" . ff-find-other-file))
  (use-package lsp-ui
    :init
    (setq lsp-ui-doc-enable t
      lsp-ui-position 'at-point)
    :hook
    (lsp-mode . lsp-ui-mode))

For example, when I'm typing an "m", it gives me the completion for malloc and imports <cstdio> at the beginning of the files.

[emacs.se] might be a better place to ask.

lsp-enable-wich-key-integration - Google suggests lsp-enable-w*h*ich-key-integration is correct.

You say it imports <cstdio> for malloc() — that's odd since malloc() is declared in <cstdlib> rather than <cstdio>.

How does your compile_commands.json look like? Does it contain invocations to the C++ compiler?

@Martin I don't have any compile_commands.json. Am I supposed to create it ?

@KenY-N I made the modifications for the which-key thing but nothing bettter.

Yes, that's part of the clangd setup. Take a look at the clangd documentation to find out, how to do this.

I just found a tool called bear that generate a compile-commands.json file by running bear -- make but the file just contains []

Hye, I'm just digging up my post but after a while I still have the same problem and I've looked all over the internet and can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help me, please? I'll be very gratefull : )
